# Does Ejabberd Participant In Oauth2 SSO Has A Client

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, ejabberd

I am aware Ejabberd can act as an Oath2 server and provide the token that other applications can use as a SSO mechanism.  My question is can Ejabberd participate in a SSO implementation where the Oauth2 token is supplied by another Oauth server such as KeyCloak?  If so is there an example or documentation on how to do so?

ejabberd is a great messaging framework but it is a weak Oauth2 server compared to implementations such as Keycloak and does not meet our requirements in this fashion.  I believe there has got to be a way to get ejabberd to participate in SSO in 2020 and I am missing something.

Tim McClure